# Java - Null Pointer Exception passing records to a database

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, prepared-statement

i'm lopping an arraylist filtering values and passing to a database, if the record is repeated, the code throws the exception then update the values in the database and jump to the next record.
 In the record 90 , 91 or 92 i'm getting this exception

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.icc.utilidades.Conexion.actualizarEstadoAlumno(Conexion.java:4296)
at com.icc.controlador.AjaxControlador.doGet(AjaxControlador.java:227)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:51)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1041)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:603)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

The code from conexion 4296 is a method and the exception is in the line of the preparedStatement

```
public int actualizarEstadoAlumno(String rut,String estado)
{
    try {
        ConexionBd();
        System.out.println("rut "+rut);
        System.out.println("estado "+estado);
        PreparedStatement enunciado = conexion.prepareStatement("update alumno set alu_estado = ? "
                  + "where alu_rut = ? ;");
        enunciado.setString(1, rut);
        enunciado.setString(2, estado);
        enunciado.execute();
        conexion.close();
        return 1;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

When i print the values, they are not null , so why i'm getting this exception?  , The database Connection i'm sure is ok, because when i use that code  in other things this work's fine.  Before the record number 90 the code pass the values to the database correctly.
what could be the problem? help please.

this is the method where i connect to the database

```
public void ConexionBd()
{
    try 
    {
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");

        conexion = java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/final","postgres","*******");

        consulta = conexion.createStatement();  
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
}
```

Comment: Looks like `connection` or any other variable is `null`. You should always handle your exceptions. At lease use naive `e.printStacktrace()` inside the `catch` statement before returning the data.

Comment: Which line is line number 4296?

Comment: I check all the variables like connection and that is not the problem, because i use the method in others parts of the aplication and works fine. Thanks

Comment: Sorry for not post the number of line Victor, the line is PreparedStatement enunciado = conexion.prepareStatement("update alumno set alu_estado = ? "
                  + "where alu_rut = ? ;");

Comment: where does "conexion" get initialized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Null pointer exceptions occur when you are trying to refer to an object, say you're calling a method of that object, thinking the object exists but during the runtime the object doesn't exist at all.

For all the possibilities in the code where an object could be null depending on the runtime scenarios you have to put a null pointer check. I have tried to put some null pointer checks in your code, take a look below. I have also tried to correct your code a little, but it can be improved further as well. In the below code, I'm assuming conexion is a class level variable getting initialized outside of the given method.

One quick note, when it's about Null pointer exceptions, you cannot be sure of anything that goes at runtime :)

```
 public int actualizarEstadoAlumno(String rut,String estado)
{
    try {
        ConexionBd();
        System.out.println("rut "+rut);
        System.out.println("estado "+estado);
        if(conexion!=null){
           PreparedStatement enunciado = conexion.prepareStatement("update alumno set alu_estado = ? "
                  + "where alu_rut = ? ;");
           if(enunciado!=null){
                enunciado.setString(1, rut);
                enunciado.setString(2, estado);
                enunciado.execute();
                return 1;
           }
        }

    } catch (SQLException sqlEx) {
       //return 0;   This isn't a good way to handle exception. How will you know that SQL Exception has occurred? You need to handle the exceptions/weird things your code can run into.
       //log exception, use logger
       //print stack trace, handle the exception or throw it 
    } catch (Exception ex){
       //log exception, use logger
       //print stack trace, handle the exception or throw it 
    }finally{
         conexion.close(); // this is why finally was born.
    }
}
```

Comment: conexion it's null but only after passing 90 records, i don't know why

Comment: If conexion is null, then show us the code where you are creating & initializing conecxion. Can we see the complete code?

Comment: Can we see the complete code? Where is actualizarEstadoAlumno() called from?

Comment: this was the first step to found the solution,  catching the exception i watch the value null of the variable conexion, the problem was not in the connection method, the problem ocurrs when i'm looping the arraylist, the method ConexionBd() is called for each record acumulating resources wich produces a failure in the PostgreSQL db. The solution is to modify the method ConexionBd() to return the connection variable  and make only one time.   For that reason in the record 90 the variable conexion died.

Comment: By looking at both the methods I was pretty sure that the way actualizarEstadoAlumno() is being called has some issue. That's why I was asking to see the complete code :) Never mind, good that you resolved it. \m/

Answer (score 0):

Your data field `conexion` seems to be null, so calling `conexion.prepareStatement(..)`
throws the NPE. You should initialize the data field first before using it.

BTW. it is not a good style to simply catch the exception. You should at least log the error otherwise it is very difficult to find such errors.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anywhere you have initialized conexion. You have to use the new operator and initialize connexion within the scope of the try statement (connexion could have global scope, but I don't see it in the code snippet you have provided)

Answer (score -1):

try this :

```
    try {
                ConexionBd();
                System.out.println("rut "+rut);
                System.out.println("estado "+estado);
           if(conexion!=null){
                PreparedStatement enunciado = conexion.prepareStatement("update alumno set alu_estado = ? "
                          + "where alu_rut = ? ;");
             }else{ 
  System.out.println("conexion not initialized (null)"); 

}
              enunciado.setString(1, rut);
                enunciado.setString(2, estado);
                enunciado.execute();
                conexion.close();
                return 1;
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                return 0;
            }
```

Comment: conexion it's null but only after passing 90 records, i don't know why

Comment: so check for null in "rut" and "estado" before using them.

Comment: the value of  rut and estado is not null

Comment: @elsadek you also have an NPE in your code. You check `conexion` and if it´s null you simply ignore it. brilliant ;)

Comment: Also, you would reinitialize the connection for each record without checking, if it´s null or not..

Comment: @agim just for illustration purpose, sure he need to do something more appropriate.